# how to write a sequence of code that would let me know the amount of occurences inside a file

Tags: python

I'm givin a server log, with several files. Each file has a record of how many times the application is being run on that certain day dating back to starting January 1st (new log created everyday).
What sequence of code would let me know how many times a "GET" and "POST" request was recorded.

I was thinking about :

```
with open("file.txt", "r") as file_1:
    for line in file_1:
        if ("GET" and "POST") in line: 
            print(line)
```

Comment: Will GET and POST be in the same line? or you mean GET or POST?

Comment: They wont be in the same line but i need a count on both GET and POST in the file

Answer (score 1):

The question is not completely clear to me, but this code works if you want to count GET and POST separately.

You do not need to loop over all the lines because you can simply use the count function.

```
def main():
       file_1  = open('file.txt', 'r').read()
       GET = file_1.count("GET")
       POST = file_1.count("POST")
       print(POST)
       print(GET)

main()
```

Comment: Remember to explicitly close the file handle. Or better yet, use a context manager.

Comment: Thank you ! New to Python and this was a big help!